# I can't install whl files in bulk using python 3.7 code

Tags: python, pip

I have a windows 10 x64 pc and I want to install some libraries in virtual environment.
I am using PyCharm Professional 2019.3.3, Python 3.7.6 x64 and PIP 19.0.3
I tried this approach

```
from pip._internal import main as pipmain
path = 'D:\Python\Libraries\\'
pipmain(['install', path+'setuptools-45.2.0-py3-none-any.whl'])
```

Its working fine for a single installation but in batch installation its not working
I tried in this way

```
from pip._internal import main as pipmain
path = 'D:\Python\Libraries\\'
pipmain(['install', path+'setuptools-45.2.0-py3-none-any.whl'])
pipmain(['install', path+'numpy-1.18.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'])
pipmain(['install', path+'opencv_python-4.2.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'])
pipmain(['install', path+'scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'])
```

It shows this error

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker
```

First one is installed correctly without any error but the rest display above error

Comment: maybe it's not a bulk issue, maybe it's just one of the packages you want to install has some dependencies you need to install before it. Try to exclude one of them.

Comment: _pip_ has no official API. It is not meant to be called from code, especially not like this. If you were to edit your question to mention what the larger goal is, you might get suggestions for better alternatives.

Comment: Was able to get past this error by going to /Users/thaparp/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages and moving the numpy-1.16.1.dist-info folder out then running pip install numpy to reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks for your time.
And yes I may have missed lot of things as its my first post in Stack Overflow.
I need to install 54 libraries in 32 computers.

Comment: Why don't you use a `requirements.txt` file? This makes it so much easier to install multiple wheels all at once. Or find the right combination of `pip install` options.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of usage is explicitly discouraged and documented as likely to fail!

See [*pip*'s documentation section "*Using pip from your program*"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program):

> As noted previously, pip is a command line program. While it is implemented in Python, and so is available from your Python code via import pip, you must not use pip’s internal APIs in this way. There are a number of reasons for this:
>
> [...]
>
> 3. pip assumes that once it has finished its work, the process will terminate. It doesn’t need to handle the possibility that other code will continue to run after that point, so (for example) calling pip twice in the same process is likely to have issues.

So it's not surprising that this piece of code doesn't work as one could expect.